# I have 2 dataframes: wd_patients and wd_appointments

Tags: r

Filter male patients who completed their treatment with only one visit. Note that you will need to use the Patients data set to check if a patients’ treatment is complete or not. And you need to check the Appointments data set to check if they have had only one visit. Keep in mind that “No SHow” and “Cancelled” is not considered as a visit, and only “Attended” is considered as a visit.

Please see the structure of the data below:

Patients:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZffj.png)

Appointments:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iu4O.png)

Comment: What have you tired so far?

Comment: Please add your example data code not only image... Also I can suggest you to read function filter and inner join

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.